# responsive set middle column on top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So i have a traditional three column lay-out. The left column is like a toolbox column, the middle column is the "dynamic content" column and the right one is like a summary of data column.

What i want to achieve is that as soon as some responsiveness is going on that the center column will be on top. This will be the most important part of the website and thus should be on top. I cant seem to get this to work with bootstrap. This is my lay-out:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- column: left -->
        <div class="col-md-2" id="sidebarleft">left </div>
        <!-- column: center-->
        <div class="col-md-8" id="main">middle</div>
        <!-- column: right -->
        <div class="col-md-2" id="sidebarright">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how would i go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the push and pull classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

So the layout is intact when the browser is using Bootstrap's "**md**" viewport, however when made smaller (so "**sm**" and "**xs**") the middle column is at the top followed by the left and right.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- column: center-->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2" id="main">middle</div>
        <!-- column: left -->
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull-8" id="sidebarleft">left </div>
        <!-- column: right -->
    <div class="col-md-2" id="sidebarright">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just looking into the push and pull because DavidG mentioned it and your example exactly does what i want.This is why i love bootstrap! Thanks, this did the trick.

Comment: Aye Bootstrap is very nice, no problem!

Answer (score 1):

That's because your HTML is stacking in order of the way it's written.

A good way to achieve this would be to either:

**a)** Take a dropdown UI approach on the `#sidebarleft` or, **b)** Use JS to refactor the layout when responsive. Though, depending how much your site relies on JS, this may not be suitable from a no-js point of view. It would need a fallback. I'm not entire too sure on CSS methods with Bootstrap using the push/pull class selectors.

A jQuery solution would be to store the element ID in a variable and then tell the DOM to remove the element at a certain width. Then, tell it to `insertBefore` or `insertAfter` the `#sidebarleft` element.

```
var mainContent = $('#main');
var leftSidebar = $('#sidebarleft');

$(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).width() <= 480) {

        mainContent.remove();
        mainContent.insertBefore(leftSidebar);
    } else if ($(window).width() > 481) {

        mainContent.remove();
        mainContent.insertAfter(leftSidebar);
    } 

});
```

[Here's a Pen on the functionality in JS using jQuery.](http://codepen.io/JMDUK/pen/yHLcI)

Resize the screen to less or equal than 480 pixels and watch the main content reorder itself above the sidebar.

Comment: No need for all this when using Bootstrap. check my comment and stu177's answer.

Comment: Sorry, forgive me. I forgot what Bootstrap was for a moment.

Comment: Nothing to forgive, your answer is still technically valid. Not sure who gave you the downvote, but I'll give you +1.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this and worked great for me. The middle column goes to the left on mobile. The 3rd one goes down on tablet.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1140px;
margin: 15px auto;
}
.col {
margin-bottom: 10px
}
.rowone {
width: 75%;
float: left;
}
.rowtwo {
width: 24%;
float: right;
}
.middle {
float: right;
width: 66.6%;
background: #fe8a9e
}
.left {
float: left;
width: 32%;
background: #64c780
}
.right {
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #4690ec
}

@media (max-width: 860px) {
.rowone, .rowtwo {
width: 100%;
}
.left {
float: right
}
.middle {
float: left
}
.right .module.long {
height: 218px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
.col, .rowone, .rowtwo {
width: 100%;
}
.middle {
float: left
}
.left {
float: right
}
.rowtwo {
float: left
}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="rowone">
<div class="col middle">Middle</div>
<div class="col left">Left</div>
</div>
<div class="rowtwo">
<div class="col right">Right</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```